# Grouping multiple results into a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Here's my scenario. I have 3 Models. How should I go about grouping my ProductItems into each ProductPack. Would a stored procedure be best? If so what does it look like? I'm new to stored procedures. I don't know how to get the Entity framework to add ProductItems into the ProductPacks. I'm using the ProductPackGroups table because I needed a way to keep my product packs flexible enough to mix and match exsisting ProductItems into the ProductPacks.

ProductItems
-- Id
-- Title
-- Description

ProductPacks
-- Id
-- Title
-- Description

ProductPackGroups
-- Id
-- ProductItemId
-- ProductPackId
-- ProductItem
-- ProductPack

I run my IQueryable GetAllProductPackGroups();
Each result already contains a ProductItem Object and ProductPack object.

The result would look something like this:

{Id = 1, ProductItemId = **1**, ProductPackId = 1, ProductItem = [Object], ProductPack = [Object]}
{Id = 1, ProductItemId = **2**, ProductPackId = 1, ProductItem = [Object], ProductPack = [Object]}
{Id = 1, ProductItemId = **3**, ProductPackId = 1, ProductItem = [Object], ProductPack = [Object]}
{Id = 1, ProductItemId = **4**, ProductPackId = 1, ProductItem = [Object], ProductPack = [Object]}
{Id = 1, ProductItemId = **5**, ProductPackId = 1, ProductItem = [Object], ProductPack = [Object]}

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you mean creating new ProductPacks via C# then having them committed to the db via EntityFramework?

Comment: The ProductPackGroups query will produce multiple records all with different productItemId's but the ProductPackId's will be the same. This represents a grouping of items for a single product pack. What's the best way to group them. I want to make the minimum amount of requests to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of EF's eager fetching to minimise the number of database calls. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var productPackGroups = _dbContext.ProductPackGroups
                                  .Include(x => x.ProductPacks)
                                  .Include(x => x.Products);
```

MSDN has a [really good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/data/jj574232.aspx) on different ways to load related entities in EF.